# XStream error using Optaplanner with groovy

Tags: groovy, xstream, optaplanner

I'm trying to adapt a simple Drools Planner example found in [Drool's Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/drools-developers-using-jboss-cookbook/book) chapter 8, to OptaPlanner 6.0.1.Final using groovy (already have a working java version with maven), the classes and tests are in one groovy script and in the same folder are the solverConfig.xml and solverRules.drl, how should the XmlSolverFactory be configured to avoid:

```
groovy technicianAssignationScript.groovy
Caught: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: Cannot create XmlPullParser
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: Cannot create XmlPullParser
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:56)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1040)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.configure(XmlSolverFactory.java:84)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.configure(XmlSolverFactory.java:74)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.configure(XmlSolverFactory.java:67)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory$configure.call(Unknown Source)
        at BestAvailableTechnicianTest.findBestTechnician(technicianAssignationScript.groovy:294)
        at BestAvailableTechnicianTest$findBestTechnician.call(Unknown Source)
        at technicianAssignationScript.run(technicianAssignationScript.groovy:379)
```

I'm using

```
groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.3.0 JVM: 1.7.0_55 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

with this dependencies in the script:

```
@Grapes([
          @Grab("org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:6.0.1.Final"),
          @Grab("junit:junit:4.4"),
          @Grab("org.optaplanner:optaplanner-benchmark:6.0.1.Final"),
          // @Grab("commons-lang:commons-lang-2.6"),
          @Grab("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2"),
          @Grab("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.9"),
          @Grab("com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.3"),
          @Grab("org.jdom:jdom:1.1.3"),
          @Grab("xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c"),
          @Grab("xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1")
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using xstream 1.4.7 with xpp3_min 1.1.4c and xmlpull 1.1.3.1 on optaplanner master (6.1.0.Beta4). But IIRC, optaplanner 6.0.1 uses xstream 1.4.3, which should work perfectly too.

Try asking this question on the xstream user list: they answer a lot there.

Comment: I recently had time to create a regular maven project to read the files and there were no errors using the above dependencies, so I suspect the problem is that I can't get groovy to resolve the dependencies from my local maven repository.